# How do i search my CloudSearch domain using AWS-SDK for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I cannot find the API call to search the search domain in AWS-SDK documentation for NodeJS / JavaScript.

[CloudSearch developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/submitting-search-requests.html) suggests that AWS-SDK be used to perform search queries, yet i cannot find any API call in sdk

Link to AWS-SDK documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudSearch.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer to my own question. "CloudSearchDomain" is in another section separated from "CloudSearch". i feel silly

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudSearchDomain.html

Comment: IMO, whenever the user of something feels silly, it's the designer of it at fault.  Why are there two separate SDKs?  How would one know which to use?